# How copy a value that's text on cypress?

Tags: cypress

I've a selector assigned for a text value, I want to copy the value that's being displayed. How can I do this? The text value is saved in a span tag.

Dummy Text

cy.get('text-value'). and then what can I apply to do this action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving the text of an element usually works like this:

```js
cy.get('selector').invoke('text').as('variable_name')
```

Then you can call this variable in a later `it`instance with
`this.variable_name`

for example you want to type the text you save in another field:

```js
cy.get('other_selector').type(this.variable_name)
```

Just note that you can't put them inside the same `it` instance because of the asynchronous nature of Cypress